# Do I need docker to run azure data studio on linux ubuntu?

Tags: azure, ubuntu

I'm trying to cofigure Azure data studio on my linux laptop. I'm following the steps the microsoft docs are showing but when I try to add a new connection it says "Login failed for user ''." So do I need docker to run it?

Comment: You can refer to [Login Failed for user ''](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/133709/login-failed-for-user-39lttoken-identified-princip.html), [Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/10298) and https://www.reddit.com/r/AZURE/comments/f97nu1/create_a_login_and_a_user_on_master_db_using/fipym2u?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research docker is not required to run data studio on linux.

follow with these steps.

**1)**  We can install Azure Data Studio on Ubuntu 18.10 using both the GUI and command line mode as well. Tried with Installing  the tool using the GUI mode. To do so, open the browser (by default Mozilla is installed on Ubuntu OS) and go to this [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-2017).

[image]

**2)**     In Linux, we can see a different kind of download available

- **Deb (Debian software repository)**
- **Rpm: Package in .rpm format**
- **Tar.gz: Files in a compressed format**.

[image]

**3)**  we will perform the **Debian** installation for the **Azure Data Studio**. It is a graphical method to perform the installation on Ubuntu. Download the .**deb file** and save it in the desired location.

[image]

**4)**  Once Debian package (azuredatastudio-Linux-1.2.4.deb) download is successful, double-click on the file to launch the installation as shown below.

[image]

**5)**  Before installation, authentication is required for this. Enter the administrator user id and password we created while installing Ubuntu 18.10.

[image]

**6)** Once the installation is complete, you can see the **Remove** box in red color. It shows that we have installed Azure Data Studio successfully.

[image]

**7)**  In the Ubuntu application, you can verify the **Azure Data Studio** is present.

[image]

**8)**. **Double click** on it to launch the **Azure Data Studio initial screen**.

[image]

**9).** Enter the connection details like instance name, authentication method (SQL authentication), database name (if we want to connect to the specific database) and the server group

[image]

**10)**  And we are connected to the SQL Server preview version from inside the virtual machine hosting Ubuntu 18.10. You can verify the server instance version, edition, computer name from the server dashboard launched after connecting to the SQL Server.

[image]

For more details refer this [document](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2019-on-linux-with-ubuntu-and-azure-data-studio/)